# Error of saving data of one email to the another email

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The code below is running fine but when logging in, one Gmail id data is saved into the another Gmail id. That is, when logging in through one Gmail I get the data of another Gmail id which was signed up before and I can log in in only one Gmail id which is signed up at the initial condition. And when logging in the initial v, the database which is signed up at the last is shown in the database.

```
       fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String uid = fAuth.getUid();

    fUserDatabase = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid);

    Register_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uEmail = inEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String uName = inName.getText().toString().trim();
            String uPassword = inPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String uRePassword = inRePassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String uContact = inContact.getText().toString().trim();
            String uAddress = inAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            String uSkill = inSkill.getText().toString().trim();
            String uExp = inExp.getText().toString().trim();
            String uQual = inQual.getText().toString().trim();
            register_user(uName 
,uEmail,uPassword,uRePassword,uAddress,uContact,uSkill,uQual,uExp);
          }
    });
}

private void register_user(final String name, final String email, String 
password, String rePassword, final String address, final String 
contact, final String Skill, final String Qualification, final String Exp) 
 {

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Processing your data, Please wait . . .");
progressDialog.show();



fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                String id = fAuth.getUid();
                                user_details user = new 
user_details(id,name,address,contact,email,Qualification,Exp,Skill);
                                fUserDatabase.setValue(user);

                                Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "User has 
been created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(JobSignup.this, 
Uploadimage.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(JobSignup.this, "Error: 
 "+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


    }
});
```

Comment: Can u post your database structure. And also ful code.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I have added image there in enter a image description of above link and also full code is added above @Raj

Comment: above is the image for database@AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried to use `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: yes but that is not working.what should i do?@AlexMamo